# GWT Dev Mode server not working

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have installed GWT and the Eclipse plugin, when I try to run a new project as per http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html#creating everything seems fine

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed C:\Users\john\workspaceAndroid\WebTest\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed C:\Users\john\workspaceAndroid\WebTest\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

and I get the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/WebTest.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

but when I put it in a web browser I get this

```
SOAP-ENV:Client HTTP GET method not implemented
```

The only thing I can find on Google is a possible conflict with another service using that port, but thats not the case for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the default project that the wizard creates or added any jars? It's odd that you should get a SOAP error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Eclipse as admin (Right-click Run as Administrator)